# Feedparser SAXParseException, bozo:1

Tags: exception, rss, saxparser, feedparser

I'm using feedparser in a script that's generally working for RSS URLs, but there's one URL that's giving me a headache: [tabbforum.com/feed.atom](http://tabbforum.com/feed.atom)

I get a `SAXParseException('not well-formed (invalid token)',)`.

```
import feedparser

def read_from_feed(self, rss_url):
    feed = feedparser.parse(rss_url)
    for entry in feed.entries:
        print('do stuff')


>>>>feed
{'feed': {}, 'entries': [], 'bozo': 1, 'encoding': 'utf-8', 'version': '', 'bozo_exception': SAXParseException('not well-formed (invalid token)',), 'namespaces': {}}
```

I'm thinking that there's something wrong with the xml(?). Has anybody had previous experiences and have been able to find a work-around? Or have an idea what the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had a similar problem. In my case I forgot to put `http://` in front of URL and feedparser was treating it not as a url, but as an RSS XML.

Comment: It works! I was so sure I tried this, but apparently not. Thank you!

Comment: My problem was worng path to xml file :)